# How to use a class variable as a default argument value in Python

Tags: python, class, static, parameter-passing, static-methods

I want to use a class variable as a default argument value in a static method.
But when I reference the class, I get an error `NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined`

```
class MyClass:

    x = 100
    y = 200

    @staticmethod
    def foo(x = MyClass.x, y = MyClass.y):
        return x*y
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MyClass` is not defined yet when Python wants to bind the default arguments,   but `x` and `y` are already defined in the classes' scope.

In other words, you can write:

```
class MyClass:
    x = 100
    y = 200

    @staticmethod
    def foo(x=x, y=y):
        return x*y
```

Note that `foo` will *not* recognize reassignments to `MyCLass.x` and `MyClass.y` because the default arguments are bound once, when the function is created.

```
>>> MyClass.foo()
20000
>>> MyClass.x = 0
>>> MyClass.foo()
20000
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the question and this answer also apply for non-static methods?